# Is this the correct syntax, myField_ = [newValue retain]?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm trying to learn Objective C. I came across the following code which the compiler generates behind the scenes for `@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString* myField`

```
-(NSString*) myField
{
   return myField_; //assuming myField_ is the name of the field.
}

-(void) setMyField:(NSString*) newValue
{
  if(newValue != myField_)
  {
     [myField_ release];
     myField_ = [newValue retain];
  }
}
```

Now my question is; Why to call retain on newValue? Instead the following syntax should be used:

```
myField_ = newValue;
[myField_ retain];
```

Please advise why the above syntax is not used because as per my understanding, we want to retain the object pointed to by `myField_` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're the same (both are correct). You don't **copy** the object - retain returns the same pointer that was retained, so it's shorter and cleaner to write

```
ivar = [newObj retain];
```

than separately assigning and retaining the object.

Answer (score 2):

Both syntaxes are correct. In the first case we also retain the object pointed by `myField` since we assign `[newValue retain]` to it.